# How to integrate history.js with jquery.pjax?

Tags: javascript, html, pushstate, history.js, pjax

I'm beginning to play with PJAX. But there's a problem. IE9- doesnt support pushState. I found history.js to provide pushState and replaceState for old browsers but I cant use history.js in jquery.pjax. Who used history.js in jquery.pjax?

Comment: From what I can see, PJAX does some of the stuff that History.js also does, however, the latter supports both HTML4 and HTML5 browsers equally. PJAX needs to be rewritten to do what History.js do. I don't think you can just throw them in there together :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't work together and are not meant to.  History.js does everything PJAX does and better, so no need to mix the two.